# Cross Origin in ajax not working for .properties file in IOS (10.3.1)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, ios10.3

I used **[i18n](https://github.com/requirejs/i18n)** plugin for load *.properties file for translation and its working fine on android platform but same library not working on IOS 10.3.1. It gives me below error:

[image]

i have done some changes in i18n library but still its not working.

```
function loadAndParseFile(filename, settings) {
    $.ajax({
        url: filename,
        async: false,
        cache: settings.cache,
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: 'text/plain;charset=' + settings.encoding,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data, status) {
            parseData(data, settings.mode);
        }
    });
}
```

In above code:

i have been added Cross-Domain 'true' and datatype 'text'.. when i changed datatype 'text' to 'jsonp' its working but it gives .properties file error.
Please check below error..

[image]

That means. file is loaded, but inner data format is different.

Comment: Yes, the log tells you that the `Messages.properties` file is invalid ("Unexpected identifier 'User'). Is this a static file or generated? Either way: You need to fix it.

Comment: @Wukerplank Yes, Its Static file..

Comment: Are you passing a valid URL  here... `$.ajax({ url: filename, ... })`?

Comment: @joshuamabina.. Yes.. URL is Valid.. its file path

Comment: @Goku you should put that file on your server and then try to access it from the server. IOS has different file structure than windows. That is why it is working on windows and not on IOS and AJAX call needs a protocol work

Comment: @all Please give me solution.. i tried above but it didn't work..

Comment: @Goku as @Shubham said, try uploading those files into a server, the files are loading with `file://` protocol that may work in windows, but IOS is more strict and maybe its blocking those calls

Comment: You add header on ajax call

Comment: headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'Your Site Host'
    },"

Comment: JSONP works differently, you have to wrap it with callback function and resolve it to get right resource you need. This is just temp. Always use CORS headers enabled from server side.

Comment: keep the datatype text and try consoling error
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.error("Error loading file: " + error);
    console.error("Status: " + status);
    console.error(xhr);
}

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your ajax parameters

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using now JSONP instead of text, the file will be loaded as javascript code, so if contents are not valid javascript code it will fail.

Surround data with a global variable assignation or a function call:

```
    window.variable = "_DATA_"; // or
    functionName("_DATA_");
```

If _DATA_ are JSON format, then you don't need surround with quotes, otherwise you'll need to use "_DATA_" because without quotes it will not be valid javascript syntax.